# Mongo DB , Spring boot : Exception opening socket , Caused by: Connection refused

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot to connect to MongoDB but it is giving me an exception while trying to connect, the weird thing is that this was working for me before and suddenly it started giving me this error. 
Could anyone please help me out if this is the issue due to some another service is running on this port(27017), if so how could I found out that.

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:63) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:115) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:113) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:57) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:58) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
... 3 common frames omitted
```

**application.properties:**

```
    spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
    spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
    spring.data.mongodb.database=swt
```

**pom.xml:**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Is your Mongodb running on localhost and port 27017? Most likely its down or running on a different port.

Comment: @MohamedSanaulla, I have restarted my system and now it is connecting to mongo db successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by installing mongo on the VM and then running the Spring boot instance.

For me the embedded mongo driver (de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo) was not working, so I removed the dependancy.

Install Mongo & run it

- sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 9DA31620334BD75D9DCB49F368818C72E52529D4
- echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/4.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.0.list
- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
- sudo service mongod restart

Run Spring Boot Application